# border-radius-top-left is not working with Angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to curve my button from specific corners, but it is not working with my NativeScript App. Here is my CSS code:

```
border-bottom-left-radius:10;
border-top-left-radius:10;
border-top-right-radius:0;
border-bottom-right-radius:0;
```

I have tried to add px at the end, but it does not work with Angular2 CSS.
I also tried to put them all in one line like this:

border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;

but it did not work with and without px.

Comment: You should put `px` at the end (as you mentioned) but there must be some other CSS overriding these styles. Angular2 likely has nothing to do with this and instead it is another library that is overriding these styles. What other styles are being applied to the element? Also maybe you could screenshot your browsers inspector (when inspecting that element) so we can see what is overriding it. You'll see `px` is necessary by looking at my Chrome Dev Tools and you see the `10` value is invalid: http://imgur.com/a/jqEFq

Comment: Are you sure you're applying / overriding to the correct element? your first example as `10px` would be correct and angular shouldn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: Also, border-top-left-radius is not the same as border-radius-top-left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need the px

```
border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
border-top-left-radius:10px;
border-top-right-radius:0;
border-bottom-right-radius:0;
```

If that doesn't work try to add !important to overwrite the other css rules.

```
border-bottom-left-radius:10px !important;
border-top-left-radius:10px !important;
border-top-right-radius:0 !important;
border-bottom-right-radius:0 !important;
```